# Improve CGContextDrawImage performance

Tags: macos, calayer, nsview, nsscrollview, cgcontextdrawimage

I have a custom NSView that has it's own drawRect. I draw a lot of images using CGContextDrawImage into the view. The NsView is in a NSScrollView. The issue I am having is, while scrolling, the drawrect takes too long. the scrolling isn't smooth.

I did try setting wantslayer to true, to enable layer-backed drawing. Now the scrolling is smooth until the next drawrect is called, i.e till next time a new dirtyRect has to be redrawn.

Since I have to use drawrect to draw the contents, is there a way to improve scrolling performance?

if not, is there an alternative?

**Update:**

the call that's taking time.

[image]

I tried what Rob suggested below (using NSImageView for each image). that helped. I see smooth scrolling while setting the images as well.

But I would like to know why CGContextDrawImage takes time? especially rgbaf16_sample_rgbaf_inner. is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Could you just use a separate `NSImageView` for each image? Or use a separate sublayer for each image?

Comment: probably a dumb question. say I use separate NSImageView or sublayers, won't it be the same as using CGContextDrawImage since all these happen on the main thread? I would have to set the NSImageView's image as i scroll.

Comment: If you can set each image view's or layer's content once, the images get sent to the window server once. Then the window server can put the images in GPU memory and then  efficiently compose the screen image using OpenGL or Metal on the GPU.

Comment: got it thanks. one more question.. so i would see the performance hit, the first time i set the layer's content? is there a way to avoid that? since my scrollview could have 1000s of images. setting the layers at init/load may not be a good idea. i would like to set the images while scrolling.

Comment: You shouldn't be drawing every image on every call to `-drawRect:`. See [View Programming Guide: Optimizing View Drawing — Constraining Drawing to Improve Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH11-SW4).

Comment: I am not drawing every image. only the images in the dirtyrect (around 5)